# Java 15 Text Blocks in CC Mode?

Tags: cc-mode, java

Java SE 15 adds (finally) support for multiline string literals that start with `"""\n` and end with `"""`.

Has anyone updated `java-mode` (CC Mode) to recognize this construct?

Comment: It used to work for me, then regressed on upgrading from 26.3 to 27.1.  (A triple delimited string would fontify as three separate strings by default, and should look fine.  Maybe that’s how it worked in the past.)

Comment: Maybe look at python-mode for an implementation?

Comment: If you have a problem, it won't get fixed until someone files a proper bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my java mode hook to use mmm-mode here:

```
(require 'mmm-auto)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
(mmm-add-classes
 '((java-text-block
    :submode fundamental-mode
    :front ".+\"\"\"$"
    :back ".*\"\"\".*"
    :face mmm-code-submode-face
    )))
(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'java-mode "\\.java$" 'java-text-block)
```

works well enough, although I'd like a better way to make mmm-mode smarter to the content of the block. e.g. entering json-mode for json text, xml-mode for xml, etc...

I've done this previously in ruby with ruby's unique heredoc string syntax, but I can't figure out a clean way to make it work in Java.